# Proper handling of individual user access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm using Angular Fullstack. Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my syntax? I'm not sure the proper way to handle it.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. (If Auth.hasRole('admin') is true, I want it to show all orders. If the user is authenticated, I want it to show them only their orders. If the user is not authenticated, I want it to say "Unauthorized".

Here's the code

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  if(Auth.hasRole('admin')) {
    Order.find(function (err, orders) {
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.status(200).json(orders);
    });
  } else if (!Auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  } else {
    Order.find().where({ name: 'someusername' }).exec(function (err, orders) {
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.status(200).json(orders);
    });
  }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but when I access the api/orders it just hangs and times out.

Comment: Try to remove some responses and add something diferent. For example, remove  handleError for res.send('error') just to debug where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return for your first condition.
If you are testing with a user with role 'admin', there won't be a response.

```
if(Auth.hasRole('admin')) {
    Order.find(function (err, orders) {
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
       return res.status(200).json(orders);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that, however, when I visit my api (logged out) it's still showing all orders and ignoring the if() logic associated with checking for authentication.

Comment: @JaysonH if it is showing all orders, it is in fact not ignoring the if() logic, the conditionals just aren't what you think they are.

Comment: @JaysonH As KevinB said, it is not ignoring the logic, just entering on the condition it fits. But what do you mean by logged out? Maybe the Auth object is still setted?